# BQ Error:"Referenced tables are supported by different backends and cannot be used together"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I get this error :
"Referenced tables are supported by different backends and cannot be used together" when i am trying to do this :

SELECT count(1)
FROM [Project100:Dataset10.Table1] A inner join [Project200.Dataset20.Table2] B on B.id=A.id
where date(A.date)=date('20200318') LIMIT 1000

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `[Project100:Dataset10.Table1]` and `[Project200.Dataset20.Table2]`

The first one is treated as Legacy reference and the second one is as Standard SQL reference which supported by different backends

Try to use just below instead

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM [Project100:Dataset10.Table1] A 
INNER JOIN [Project200:Dataset20.Table2] B 
ON B.id=A.id 
WHERE DATE(A.date)=DATE('20200318') 
LIMIT 1000
```

Meantime, consider migrating your code to [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Will try that out